# CSS3 vs Javascript only transforms

Tags: javascript, css

Impressed by the Apple Safari 360 demo
https://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/threesixty.php

It seems to work in Firefox as well.

Can anyone summarize the pros and cons of using CSSonly vs javascript for animations and transforms?

Comment: i'd say lack of support in older browsers(css3 that is) but i have noticed css3 to be faster in some aspects when it comes to animations vs js. also css3 would be light weight (no libraries to import etc..) plus css3 supports object rotation natively

Comment: there is a lot of JavaScript involved in that page

Comment: What does that demo have to do with the rest of the question?

Comment: does [the demo](https://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/showcase/threesixty/) use CSS3 transformations?

Comment: @Bergi nope. It sets the `src` attribute of an `img` element to a series of URLs. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question at all.

Comment: Yes, I found that too. But the page loads so many resources, I can't be sure whether they did it different in specific (webkit) browsers.

Comment: @Bergi can you imagine CSS transforms contributing in any significant way to an effect like this? I can't.

Comment: You know that rotating 3D cube? OK, we're having a cylindric rotation and the iphones are no cubes. Still, it might be possible to make the transition between two images more smooth.
At least, the graphics on the screens may easily be animated with CSS-3-D transformation, making the screen images swappable :)

Answer (score 3):

My personal opinion is that, using a house as an analogy, HTML is for laying the foundations, CSS is for painting the rooms, and JS is for renovations. If you want to add a water feature, the CSS would be responsible for the appearance of the feature, but the JS would be what makes the water move through it.

Similarly, I could make a clock using CSS and have it rotate using a simple CSS animation (lasting 12 hours for the hour hand, 1 hour for the minute hand, and 1 minute for the second hand), but I would much rather make it in JavaScript as JS would be able to check the user's clock and keep itself in sync. In particular this is important if the browser lags due to the user having too much open on their computer, or just an old computer in general.

Also, I'm pretty sure CSS has to be re-evaluated several hundred times a second for animations, whereas with JS you can explicitly set the framerate to something more reasonable, such as an interval of 250ms for 4 frames per second (more than enough for clocks and progress bars) or 25ms (40fps) for more advanced animations (used occasionally in my sites since they're games). With that kind of control you can manage the efficiency of your site and so on.

On the other hand, CSS transforms are very useful - that's because they affect the appearance of the element, as CSS should. Then, using JS to control them, it's possible to create very complex animations with minimal code (for example in the aforementioned game, there is an entire sequence which would be completely impossible in pure CSS, but is made very easy in JS using CSS transforms).

It's all about using the right tool for the right job.

Comment: Why should CSS be re-evaluated? The good thing is, the UA does all the work for you like choosing an acceptable framerate, stopping animations when they're not needed etc, maybe even better hardware support. In JS you need getAnimationFrame() for that...
+1 for the last sentence.

Comment: If CSS weren't re-evaluated, explain why having a table with a few hundred rows is fine, but defining a `background-color` on `:hover` causes massive lag? :p I may not have used the right word, though, leading to confusion...